# Method Profiler for Mono for Android

Tags: performance, profiling, xamarin.android, instrumentation

Is there a method profiler for Mono for Android somewhere?

Eclipse had a cool plugin that I could use, with Mono for Android, I can't use the Profilers that ship Visual Studio as they work on the executables. Or is there a way to use them?

Update:
I asked on IRC and @jonp said something about working on one. Hopefully we'll see something soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked [this question](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodroid/2011-December/008049.html) in the Mono for Android mailing list. and I was suggested to try using [DDMS profiling tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html) as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html).

Comment: 2 of the 3 links are dead

Comment: @Gerry ok, links updated. Damn, not even Google can keep their URLs alive! :-P